# OneDrive. Access to files with a long filename using a path

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a filename on the root of OneDrive. The filename has a long name, 344 characters below a maximum 400 characters (1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222233333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444.png). When I try to get an object using a path, I get an error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-28T11:02:35",
            "request-id": "22461ea7-7ef9-4ad8-b945-ff7d3b9694d8",
            "client-request-id": "669fd185-019c-b32e-112b-c52e1732d78f"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using C# GraphClient library. How can I work with long filenames using a path?

Comment: Could you share a code how do you get files in C#?

Comment: `
                return _graphProvider.GraphClient.Users[msUserID]
                                    .Drive
                                    .Root.ItemWithPath(path)
                                    .Request()
                                    .GetAsync()
                                    .Result;
`

The same problem exists when I use GraphExplorer. For files with a short filename, the problem didn't occur for C# and GraphExplorer.

Answer (score 1):

That name exceeds the 255 characters per segment limitation in [OneDrive and SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#filenamepathlengths):

> Each segment of the path (a segment is a file name or folder name like “Promotion” or “Some File.xlsx” in the examples above) can't be more than 255 characters due to operating system limitations.

You can [get a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) the file by its `id`:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem
GET /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this limitation is only valid for PC or Mac synchronization. If this is not needed then this limitation does not exist.

I can't use id because I don't know it. I only know a path for a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can list the children of the parent drive, and get the corresponding driveItemId for this file.

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
```